# Getting error at the time of run .sh script from DockerFile

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, shell

My DockerFile is :

```
FROM postgres:latest


VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data

ARG PG_POSTGRES_PWD=123qwe
ARG DBUSER=postgres
ARG DBUSER_PWD=123qwe
ARG DBNAME=docker_pg_sh
ARG DB_DUMP_FILE=gtma_latest.sql

ENV POSTGRES_DB docker_pg_sh
ENV POSTGRES_USER postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD ${PG_POSTGRES_PWD}
ENV PGDATA /pgdata

COPY wait-for-pg-isready.sh /tmp/wait-for-pg-isready.sh
COPY ${DB_DUMP_FILE} /gtma_latest.sql 

RUN set -e && \
    nohup bash -c "docker-entrypoint.sh postgres & " && \
    /tmp/wait-for-pg-isready.sh && \
    psql -U postgres -c "CREATE USER ${DBUSER} WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${DBUSER_PWD}';" && \
    psql -U ${DBUSER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB} -c "CREATE DATABASE ${DBNAME} TEMPLATE template0;" && \
    pg_restore -v --no-owner --role=${DBUSER} --exit-on-error -U ${DBUSER} -d ${DBNAME} </gtma_latest.sql && \
    psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER ${DBUSER} WITH NOSUPERUSER;" && \
    rm -rf /gtma_latest.sql
    
    HEALTHCHECK --interval=30s --timeout=30s --start-period=5s --retries=3 \
  CMD pg_isready -U postgres -d docker_pg_sh
```

and wait-for-pg-isready.sh  file is :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

get_non_lo_ip() {
  local _ip _non_lo_ip _line _nl=$'\n'
  while IFS=$': \t' read -a _line ;do
    [ -z "${_line%inet}" ] &&
        _ip=${_line[${#_line[1]}>4?1:2]} &&
        [ "${_ip#127.0.0.1}" ] && _non_lo_ip=$_ip
    done< <(LANG=C /sbin/ifconfig)
  printf ${1+-v} $1 "%s${_nl:0:$[${#1}>0?0:1]}" $_non_lo_ip
}

get_non_lo_ip NON_LO_IP
until pg_isready -h $NON_LO_IP -U "postgres" -d "docker_pg_sh"; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is not ready - sleeping..."
  sleep 4
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - you can execute commands now"
```

Both file are in same folder.

But when I run the command `docker build -t gmta-test-sh-vol:1.0.0 .` , I am getting error
like this :

```
Step 14/15 : RUN set -e &&     nohup bash -c "docker-entrypoint.sh postgres & " &&          /tmp/wait-for-pg-isready.sh &&     psql -U postgres -c "CREATE USER ${DBUSER} WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${DBUSER_PWD}';" &&     psql -U ${DBUSER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB} -c "CREATE DATABASE ${DBNAME} TEMPLATE template0;" &&     pg_restore -v --no-owner --role=${DBUSER} --exit-on-error -U ${DBUSER} -d ${DBNAME} </gtma_latest.sql &&     psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER ${DBUSER} WITH NOSUPERUSER;" &&     rm -rf /gtma_latest.sql
---> Running in a791e734c6df
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/wait-for-pg-isready.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c set -e &&     nohup bash -c "docker-entrypoint.sh postgres & " &&     /tmp/wait-for-pg-isready.sh &&     psql -U postgres -c "CREATE USER ${DBUSER} WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${DBUSER_PWD}';" &&     psql -U ${DBUSER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB} -c "CREATE DATABASE ${DBNAME} TEMPLATE template0;" &&     pg_restore -v --no-owner --role=${DBUSER} --exit-on-error -U ${DBUSER} -d ${DBNAME} </gtma_latest.sql &&     psql -U postgres -c "ALTER USER ${DBUSER} WITH NOSUPERUSER;" &&     rm -rf /gtma_latest.sql' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

But there is no error when the line   for copy the file  wait-for-pg-isready.sh  is running .
How can the problem will be solved?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the standard `postgres` image, and put these initialization files in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` directory?  Note, because of the `VOLUME` (which is also in the base image) you cannot create a new image with this data preloaded.

Comment: I need both work together. Create the database and restore the backup, that I can run only one docker command for both task @DavidMaze